# How to add path variable to job shell

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I am setting up Jenkins to replace our current TeamCity CI build.

I have created a free-style software project so that I can execute a shell script.
The Shell script runs the mvn command.

But the build fails complaining that the 'mvn' command cannot be found.

I have figured that this is because Jenkins is running the build in a different shell, which does not have Maven on it's path.

My question is; how do I add the path so 'mvn' is found in my Shell script? I've looked around but can't spot where the right place might be.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by exporting and setting the Path in the Jenkins Job configuration where you can enter shell commands. So I set the environments variable before I execute my Shell script, works a treat.

Answer (score 3):

Some possible solutions:

- You can call maven with an absolute path
- You configure a global environment variable in the jenkins system settings with the absolute path to your maven instance, and use this in your script call (if you use the inline shell script, I don't know if those are substituted to a called script, you have to test)
- You use a maven project and configure your maven instance in the jenkins system settings

ps.: Usually `/bin/sh` is chosen from Jenkins, if you want to switch to eg. bash, you can configure this in the jenkins system settings, in case you want to configure global environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [envInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). It's very powerful.

I use it to install rbenv. And it can inject environment variables into your current job.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to Dags suggestion is that if you're only using a single version of maven, on each slave server you could do either;
 * add PATH=${PATH}:
 * symlink mvn into /usr/bin with; sudo ln -s  /usr/bin

I'm not at a Jenkins box at the moment, but I can find some more detailed examples if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is using sh by default and not bash. 
This is my first time defining a jenkins maven job, and I also followed soem regular maven instructions (for running from command line...), and tried to update ~/.bashrc with M2_HOME, M2, PATH, but it didn't work because jenkins used sh and not bash. Then I found out that there is a simpler and better way built into jenkins.

After installing maven, I was supposed to configure my maven installation in jenkins.

**To configure your maven installation in Jenkins:**

1. login to jenkins web console
2. click *Manage Jenkins* --> Configure System
3. Under Maven, click the "Maven Installations..." button
4. **a.** Give it some name
   **b.** and under MVN_HOME set the path to where you installed maven, for example "/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.5"
5. Click Save button

**Define a job with maven target**

1. edit your job
2. Click "Add build step"
3. on Maven Version, enter the name you gave your maven installation (step #4 above)
4. set some goal like clean install